# Software similar to "universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3" that runs on Ubuntu?

Tags: software-recommendation, live-usb, fedora

Can anyone please recommend an application similar to [universal-usb-installer](http://www.pendrivelinux.com/universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3/)?

I intended to run this software on my Ubuntu 14.10 regular desktop and to create a Fedora USB boot disk.

I don't have a Windows PC so I can't use universal-usb-installer-easy-as-1-2-3.

I have already tried YUMI on Ubuntu, but it cant detect the pendrive no matter what I try.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the built-in "Startup Disk Creator" if you need it for Ubuntu.
If you need to install another OS, check UNetbootin

Comment: startup disk creator has no option for fedora and unetbooting  seems great though i ended up with boot time errot 'no default or UI configuration directive found' .. so gave it up.. thanks for your support any way..

Comment: UNetbootin worked for other installation........

Answer (score 1):

You can install [Fedora Media Writer](https://github.com/MartinBriza/MediaWriter), either by downloading and building for Ubuntu, or by installing the Flatpak, which should work on recent Ubuntu. Get the latest one from the [releases](https://github.com/MartinBriza/MediaWriter/releases) page. (Note that there is a deb version listed there, but as of the latest it says *"The .deb probably doesn't work right, please report any problems. Should support Debian Jessie and above and Ubuntu 16.04 and above."* — help wanted, I guess!)

Note: We *really* do not recommend UNetbootin. It does not always get things right.

Comment: Did you Fedora Media Writer in Ubuntu? Or have you only used it in Fedora?

Comment: I have only used it on Fedora, but it should work just fine on Ubuntu. I know the Flatpak at least has been tested.

Comment: It would be useful, if you can test and confirm that it works like you recognize it also in Ubuntu :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try installing UUI with wine. If you don't have wine, you can find it in the Ubuntu Software Center. That said, UUI didn't work for me when I used Fedora iso. But you could always try. Or just use dd.

Personally, the fedora live usb creator is the most reliable, but you will need to compile it.

Comment: didnt use wine.. but surely will check 'fedora live usb creator' from source next time.. thanks for your support

Answer (score 0):

You can try **[mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)**. There is a [quick start manual[image]](http://phillw.net/isos/linux-tools/mkusb/mkUSB-quick-start-manual.pdf).

- *mkusb* works in Ubuntu and many other linux distros in order to create *live-only USB pendrives and memory cards* for booting live sesisons and install linux distros that provide hybrid iso files (most modern linux distros provide hybrid iso files).
- *mkusb* can create *persistent live* drives from Ubuntu, Debian and distros/re-spins based on them.
- *mkusb* can *wipe* and *restore* USB pendrives and memory cards to make them 'fresh' again.

See also the following link to the Ubuntu help page with more details,

[help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb)